# Magento 2 indexer:reindex Command Not Working

Tags: magento2, command-line, command

[image]
when i run command

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

it don't reindex all indexers.

but when i run

```
php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

the the following error

Please advice your best ..

Comment: which magento version you are using

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in screenshot you are adding memory limit after bin/magento.
you will need to add memory limit before bin/magento

```
php -dmemory_limit=2G bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: still same issue. 

https://snag.gy/M3EDCI.jpg

Comment: Does the commands running ?

Comment: Design Config Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00

Comment: after command it says..
Design Config Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00

Comment: Try this command. and send me screenshot of output
php -dmemory_limit=2G bin/magento indexer:reindex customer_grid

Answer (score 0):

Just Delete these folders:

-var/cache

-var/page_cache

-var/view_preprocessed

Then Try your command.

if this will not work,then go to php.ini file and increase memory_limit(size).

Answer (score 0):

**You need to Justify `-dmemory_limit=-1`**

Answer (score 0):

**You are Adding Memory Limit After bin/magento**

**You Need To Justify -dmemory_limit=-1**

> **-1 is for Unlimitaed memory**

```
php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento indexer:reindex
```